# wp_tag_cloud как удалить лишние ссылки категории

Tags: wordpress

Нужно убрать лишные ссылки категории. Откуда они вышли - непонятно. 
Вообще, не должны были выходит ссылки категории.
[image: не пойму почему выходят ссылки категории в облаках тега]

По идее, хотел простой список тегов в виде:

```
<ul> 
  <li><a>tags-1</a></li>
  <li><a>tags-2</a></li>
  <li><a>tags-3</a></li>
  <li><a>tags-4</a></li>
  <li><a>tags-5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Версия WordPress 4.7.5 ru

Answer (score 0):

Все, уже нашел ошибку, в одном месте забыл поставить знак =

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сам создал ошибку по невнимательности 
когда переопределял HTML разметку  в списках категории, если кому интересно код ниже

```
function wptuts_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'wptuts' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Виджет в этой форме будет выводится во всех постах и на всех страницах.', 'wptuts' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar_wrap %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="side_bar_heading"><h6>',
        'after_title'   => '</h6></div>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wptuts_widgets_init' );

function wptuts_widgets_categories($args)
{
  $walker = new Walker_Categories_Wptuts();
  $args = array_merge($args, array ('walker' => $walker ) );
  return $args;
}

add_filter('widget_categories_args', 'wptuts_widgets_categories' );

class Walker_Categories_Wptuts extends Walker_Category
{
 /**
   * Starts the list before the elements are added.
   *
   * @since 2.1.0
   * @access public
   *
   * @see Walker::start_lvl()
   *
   * @param string $output Used to append additional content. Passed by reference.
   * @param int    $depth  Optional. Depth of category. Used for tab indentation. Default 0.
   * @param array  $args   Optional. An array of arguments. Will only append content if style argument
   *                       value is 'list'. See wp_list_categories(). Default empty array.
   */
  public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
     parent::start_lvl( $output, $depth, $args);
  }

  /**
   * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
   *
   * @since 2.1.0
   * @access public
   *
   * @see Walker::end_lvl()
   *
   * @param string $output Used to append additional content. Passed by reference.
   * @param int    $depth  Optional. Depth of category. Used for tab indentation. Default 0.
   * @param array  $args   Optional. An array of arguments. Will only append content if style argument
   *                       value is 'list'. See wp_list_categories(). Default empty array.
   */
  public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    parent::end_lvl( $output, $depth, $args);
  }

  /**
   * Starts the element output.
   *
   * @since 2.1.0
   * @access public
   *
   * @see Walker::start_el()
   *
   * @param string $output   Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
   * @param object $category Category data object.
   * @param int    $depth    Optional. Depth of category in reference to parents. Default 0.
   * @param array  $args     Optional. An array of arguments. See wp_list_categories(). Default empty array.
   * @param int    $id       Optional. ID of the current category. Default 0.
   */
  public function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/category-template.php */
    $cat_name = apply_filters(
      'list_cats',
      esc_attr( $category->name ),
      $category
    );

    // Don't generate an element if the category name is empty.
    if ( ! $cat_name ) {
      return;
    }

    $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $category ) ) . '" ';
    if ( $args['use_desc_for_title'] && ! empty( $category->description ) ) {
      /**
       * Filters the category description for display.
       *
       * @since 1.2.0
       *
       * @param string $description Category description.
       * @param object $category    Category object.
       */
      $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"';
    }

    $link .= '><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    $link .= $cat_name;
    if ( ! empty( $args['show_count'] ) ) {
      $link .= ' <span>' . number_format_i18n( $category->count ) . '</span>';
    }
    $link .= '</a>';

    if ( ! empty( $args['feed_image'] ) || ! empty( $args['feed'] ) ) {
      $link .= ' ';

      if ( empty( $args['feed_image'] ) ) {
        $link .= '(';
      }

      $link .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_feed_link( $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy, $args['feed_type'] ) ) . '"';

      if ( empty( $args['feed'] ) ) {
        $alt = ' alt="' . sprintf(__( 'Feed for all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name ) . '"';
      } else {
        $alt = ' alt="' . $args['feed'] . '"';
        $name = $args['feed'];
        $link .= empty( $args['title'] ) ? '' : $args['title'];
      }

      $link .= '>';

      if ( empty( $args['feed_image'] ) ) {
        $link .= $name;
      } else {
        $link .= "<img src='" . $args['feed_image'] . "'$alt" . ' />';
      }
      $link .= '</a>';

      if ( empty( $args['feed_image'] ) ) {
        $link .= ')';
      }
    }


    if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) {
      $output .= "\t<li";
      $css_classes = array(
        'cat-item',
        'cat-item-' . $category->term_id,
      );

      if ( ! empty( $args['current_category'] ) ) {
        // 'current_category' can be an array, so we use `get_terms()`.
        $_current_terms = get_terms( $category->taxonomy, array(
          'include' => $args['current_category'],
          'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );

        foreach ( $_current_terms as $_current_term ) {
          if ( $category->term_id == $_current_term->term_id ) {
            $css_classes[] = 'current-cat';
          } elseif ( $category->term_id == $_current_term->parent ) {
            $css_classes[] = 'current-cat-parent';
          }
          while ( $_current_term->parent ) {
            if ( $category->term_id == $_current_term->parent ) {
              $css_classes[] =  'current-cat-ancestor';
              break;
            }
            $_current_term = get_term( $_current_term->parent, $category->taxonomy );
          }
        }
      }

      /**
       * Filters the list of CSS classes to include with each category in the list.
       *
       * @since 4.2.0
       *
       * @see wp_list_categories()
       *
       * @param array  $css_classes An array of CSS classes to be applied to each list item.
       * @param object $category    Category data object.
       * @param int    $depth       Depth of page, used for padding.
       * @param array  $args        An array of wp_list_categories() arguments.
       */
      $css_classes = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'category_css_class', $css_classes, $category, $depth, $args ) );

      $output .=  ' class="' . $css_classes . '"';
      $output .= ">$link\n";
    } elseif ( isset( $args['separator'] ) ) {
      $output .= "\t$link" . $args['separator'] . "\n";
    } else {
      $output .= "\t$link<br />\n";
    }
  }

  /**
   * Ends the element output, if needed.
   *
   * @since 2.1.0
   * @access public
   *
   * @see Walker::end_el()
   *
   * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
   * @param object $page   Not used.
   * @param int    $depth  Optional. Depth of category. Not used.
   * @param array  $args   Optional. An array of arguments. Only uses 'list' for whether should append
   *                       to output. See wp_list_categories(). Default empty array.
   */
  public function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    parent::end_el( $output, $page, $depth, $args );
  }


}
```

Comment: Такие вопросы подлежат закрытию на основании "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса."